# java return value always returns null

Tags: java, android, scope

A newbie question. I came from ruby background and want to know how to solve this problem.

Whenever I try to return a value that is initialized within a function, it prints `null` or `nothing`. Can anyone tell me how to return the value?

This is what I tried.

```
firstFunction(){
    String id = setSpinner();
}


    public String setSpinner(){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            final String[] id = new String[1];
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(user_activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,brand_list);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    id[0] = _ids.get(i);
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), id[0] + ":" + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Prints correct value
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), id[0].toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Always prints null
            return id[0]; // returns empty string
        }
```

Comment: What is _ids. Is it populated correctly?

Comment: It seems you are not able to assign any value to` id[0]` and hence it always returns null. Can you debug the code once?

Comment: before return .... try to print the value of id[0]

Comment: @Knosso `_ids` is array of some elements.

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal i can print values within `setOnItemSelectedListener`. But not outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused on *when* the code is executed.

`id[0]` will only be assigned when a spinner item is selected. All you're doing here is setting up the spinner, but there is no user-interaction at this point. Therefore, you can't receive a result, as none was selected.

If you want to return the first value, you can do that *outside of the* `OnItemSelectedListener`, like so:

`return adapter.getItem(0);`

Regardless, the code in your Listener is essentially pointless.

Comment: at `setOnItemSelectedListener`  i populate the spinner element with `brand_list` array. And i am trying to get the `id` in the position `i` from `_ids` array. And wants to return it to other function.]

Comment: Agree with @323go id[0] will get value when you select the item.

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal @323go There is already values are populated to spinner elements using `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` and `brand_list`. When user selects some elements from spinner items i am trying to get "value" `i`from `_ids` array based on the position `i`.

Comment: Added some help to the answer. You might want to read up on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) as you still seem a bit unclear on how this all fits together.